# Mudar conteúdo da página quando clicar em link no VueJS

Tags: javascript, front-end, vue.js, lado-do-cliente

Tenho uma aplicação de emails e tenho um menu lateral com todas as caixas de email que estarão disponíveis para o usuário. Segue imagem:

[image: Atualmente está na caixa de entrada]

O que eu quero fazer é:

Cada vez que eu selecionar(clicar) um item daquele menu ele recarrega somente o conteúdo da página, sem recarregar a página como um todo, ou seja, mudar somente o que o usuário está vendo sem recarregar a página inteira.

É possível??

Comment: Creio que com o uso de Ajax auxiliando o Vue.js você consegue fazer o que deseja.

Comment: Ok, vou dar uma pesquisada no assunto, obrigado pela ajuda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode esconder e mostrar os blocos conforme o lugar que está selecionando ou fazer um sistema de rotas, no caso do Vue, utilizar o **[Vue-router](http://www.vuejs-brasil.com.br/vue-router/)**

Um exemplo simples de como esconder/mostrar blocos pode ser da seguinte maneira:

```
<div id="app">
  <a href="#" v-on:click="deixarAtivo('div1')">Carros</a>
  <a href="#" v-on:click="deixarAtivo('div2')">Marcas</a>

  <div class="div1" v-show="estaAtiva('div1')">
    Conteudo 1
  </div>

  <div class="div2" v-show="estaAtiva('div2')">
    Conteudo 2
  </div>
</div>

<script>
    var app = new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            data: {
                mostrar: 'div1',
            },
           methods: {
                deixarAtivo: function(val) {
                    this.mostrar = val;
                },
                estaAtiva: function(val) {
                    return this.mostrar === val;
                },
            }
   });
</script>
```

Comment: Entendi a lógica, mas para fazer isso tem como ser da seguinte maneira: Para cada caixa de email eu criar um componente(.vue) e cada vez que for clicado na opção escolhida o componente ser renderizado??